# How do I reference an alias in a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Here's my statement:

```
SELECT 
  C.Account, 
  (RTRIM(N.FIRST) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(N.MIDDLE)) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(N.LAST)) + ' ' + LTRIM(N.SUFFIX)) AS OwnerName,
  DateAdd(dd, -1, C.ExpirationDate) as RealExpirationDate, 
  C.Description, 
  C.Type
FROM CARD as C
  INNER JOIN NAME as N ON C.Account = N.Account
WHERE (RealExpirationDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
  AND C.Type IN(10,15,17,25)
```

I keep getting an error saying that `RealExpirationDate` is an invalid column name.  How can I reference that alias?

Comment: One of the things that should be on MS's todo list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't in your code above, remember `WHERE` happens before `SELECT`, so you'd have to use:

`WHERE DateAdd(dd, -1, C.ExpirationDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate`

The most common way to alias something like this would be some inner view / query like so:

```
SELECT
  n.FooBar,  --here we can use FooBar
  t.BarFoo
FROM
  MyTable t
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT
   myTestCase as FooBar
 From MyTable2
) n
```

Comment: @JNK - its the most common way.  Besides this is a wiki like site - edit if you don't like and back it up with examples.  Simple right?

Comment: Yep.  I added an alternate method.  I'll edit it for you :)  Also +1 for explaining the why (WHERE before SELECT)

Answer (score 2):

You actually shouldn't try to reuse the alias in this case. It isn't sargable (Can't do a range seek on `ExpirationDate`).

Just use

```
WHERE C.ExpirationDate 
  BETWEEN DateAdd(dd, 1, @StartDate)  AND DateAdd(dd, 1, @EndDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference an alias. Your query would have to be

```
SELECT 
  C.Account, 
  (RTRIM(N.FIRST) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(N.MIDDLE)) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(N.LAST)) + ' ' + LTRIM(N.SUFFIX)) AS OwnerName,
  DateAdd(dd, -1, C.ExpirationDate) as RealExpirationDate, 
  C.Description, 
  C.Type
FROM CARD as C
  INNER JOIN NAME as N ON C.Account = N.Account
WHERE (DateAdd(dd, -1, C.ExpirationDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
  AND C.Type IN(10,15,17,25)
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can do this using [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx).  This is simpler than a subselect, but I'm not sure if there is a performance difference.

```
SELECT 
  C.Account, 
  (RTRIM(N.FIRST) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(N.MIDDLE)) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(N.LAST)) + ' ' + LTRIM(N.SUFFIX)) AS OwnerName,
  RealExpirationDate, 
  C.Description, 
  C.Type
FROM CARD as C
  INNER JOIN NAME as N ON C.Account = N.Account
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT DateAdd(dd, -1, C.ExpirationDate)) CrossA(RealExpirationDate)
WHERE (RealExpirationDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
  AND C.Type IN(10,15,17,25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT 
  C.Account, 
  (RTRIM(N.FIRST) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(N.MIDDLE)) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(N.LAST)) + ' ' + LTRIM(N.SUFFIX)) AS OwnerName,
  DateAdd(dd, -1, C.ExpirationDate) as RealExpirationDate, 
  C.Description, 
  C.Type
FROM CARD as C
INNER JOIN NAME as N ON C.Account = N.Account
WHERE (DateAdd(dd, -1, C.ExpirationDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
AND C.Type IN(10,15,17,25)
```

or

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT C.Account, 
  (RTRIM(N.FIRST) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(N.MIDDLE)) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(N.LAST)) + ' ' + LTRIM(N.SUFFIX)) AS OwnerName,
  DateAdd(dd, -1, C.ExpirationDate) as RealExpirationDate, 
  C.Description, 
  C.Type
FROM CARD as C
INNER JOIN NAME as N ON C.Account = N.Account
WHERE C.Type IN(10,15,17,25)
) t
WHERE RealExpirationDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: You'd need `t.RealExpirationDate`.

Comment: @JonH If you insist 8-) But not obligatory

Comment: Which of these would be more efficient?  I'm assuming the first one?

Comment: @Chris - The most efficient way is to not perform a `WHERE` filter on a calculated expression at all.